# vb.net XML with same tags

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have this XML:

```
<results start="1" max="-1">
  <result id="c32d93ab-8c3f-4af4-abfd-cb6d4887fcf0">
    <name>name1</name>
    <owner>
      <name>admin</name>
    </owner>

    <detection>
      <result id="54fb1b7b-fc21-4057-abeb-c414f17b89ba">
        <details>
          <detail>
            <name>product name</name>
          </detail>
        </details>
      </result>
    </detection>
    </result>
  <result id="c32d93ab-8c3f-4af4-abfd-cb6d4887fcf1">
    <name>name2</name>
    <owner>
      <name>admin</name>
    </owner>

    <detection>
      <result id="54fb1b7b-fc21-4057-abeb-c414f17b89bb">
        <details>
          <detail>
            <name>product name2</name>
          </detail>
        </details>
      </result>
    </detection>
  </result>
</results>
```

This is a rough example of the XML I have to parse.  I have written the following code, and right now I am just trying to get the first name in each set of data so in this case I want to grab "name1" and "name2" The issue is the result tag is being used twice in the XML in different ways once at the top and once inside the detection tag.  So when my code runs I get "name1" returned the first msgbox and then the next msgbox is blank because it seems to be grabbing the next result that is inside of detection instead of dropping down to the next one.  Is there a way to tell it not to go into the detection tag so it wont grab that result, or is there just an all around better way to approach this issue?  Here is my code:

```
    xmldoc = "*.xml"

    Do While xmldoc <> ""
        Dim xdocument As XDocument = XDocument.Load(sDir & xmldoc)

        'Get results
        Dim results = xdocument.Descendants("result")
        For Each result As XElement In results
            Dim sName = result.Element("name")
            MsgBox(sName, vbOKOnly, "Debug-sName")
        Next result
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your xml posting to fix the xml file so it is valid.  Here is a solution using Xml linq :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim results = doc.Descendants("results").Elements("result").Select(Function(x) New With { _
                .id = x.Attribute("id"), _
                .name = x.Element("name").Value,
                .owner = x.Element("owner").Element("name").Value,
                .detectionId = x.Descendants("result").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("id").Value,
                .detection = x.Element("detection").Descendants("name").Select(Function(y) y.Value).FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Yes this is correct it seems my above post did not paste correctly.